# Two-variable limit

Tags: limits

please, 
don't you have any hint how to solve this limit of two variables $x, \ y \in \Bbb R$?

$$ \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{-6 y^3 - \frac{1}{4}xy^2 +8yx^2}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} $$

I've just started with this limits and that's why I have problems with it. I really don't know what to do. If there would'nt be that square root, I would try to work somehow with that polynoms and then shorten something, however, I have no idea how to get rid of that root...

I would be happy for any help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use polar coordinates.  $x=r\cos\theta$, $y-r\sin\theta$, and take the limit as $r\to0$.
(Note: don't take $\theta\to0$, just $r\to0$.)

Comment: And is there any way how to do it without using polar coordinates?

Comment: Notice that $|y/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}|<1$ and $|x/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}|<1$

Comment: Oh, thanks really much, this helped a lot! Now it's clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Here are some useful methods with two-variable limits:

- You can just substitute $x$ and $y$ with $0$, in your case that would lead divising with $0$, so it is not a good method
- You can use the substitution $y=mx$, so you will get a limit with only one variable, $x$.
- You can use the iterating limes. First, you do $x \rightarrow 0$, then $y \rightarrow 0$, then $y \rightarrow 0, x \rightarrow 0$. If they are the same, that is your lim, if they aren't lim doesn't exist.
- The best method is using polar coordinates. $x=r*cos \alpha, y=r*sin \alpha$, and you only need to take $r \rightarrow 0$. If this leads to a lim with no $r$ at the end, then limes doesn't exist.

Comment: If you use polar coordinates, you are dividing by $r$, since $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = \sqrt{r^2*cos^2 \alpha + r^2*sin^2 \alpha} = \sqrt{r^2} = r$

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess that my problem is that I've done only few limits so far, so if I'm trying to do some, I just don't see what should I use, so I try everything I know and usually I find out that nothing works... However, I hope it will improve, and this seems to be usefull to know. Thank you.

Comment: Polar coordinates work every time (I think),  and it is a very useful method to make the two variables only one.